Generate many random alphanumeric strings
From inside of awk, I want to generate a string of X alphanumeric characters reasonably random (i.e., random but not cryptographic) on demand and rapidly.
In Ruby, I could do this:
ruby -e '
def rand_string(len, min=48, max=123, pattern=/[[:alnum:]]/)
    rtr=""
    while rtr.length<len do
        rtr+=(0..len).map { (min + rand(max-min)).chr }.
            select{|e| e[pattern] }.join
    end                     # falls out when min length achieved 
    rtr[0...len]
end

(0..5).each{|_| puts rand_string(20)}'  

Prints:
61ihPbceigvQ2nFv8s7f
JiL0Lucw6IJl87rLQgEm
lKEjaTi9jSVWFF1V6Zyn
T3jKdEuAnMeaNUl85ABF
3ct0OBbHpAp72AtKtLCk
wmNqCK3lWz74vk2Zme01

For a time comparison, that Ruby can produce 1,000,000 unique strings (no duplicates) in roughly 9 seconds.
Taking that, I tried in awk:
awk -v r=$RANDOM '
# the r value will only be a new seed each invocation -- not each f call
function rand_string(i) {
    s=""
    min=48
    max=123
    srand(r)
    while (length(s)<i) {
        c=sprintf("%c", int(min+rand()*(max-min+1)))
        if (c~/[[:alnum:]]/) s=s c
    }
    return s
}
BEGIN{ for (i=1; i<=5; i++) {print rand_string(20)}}'

That does not work -- same seed, same string result. Prints:
D65CsI55zTsk5otzSoJI
D65CsI55zTsk5otzSoJI
D65CsI55zTsk5otzSoJI
D65CsI55zTsk5otzSoJI
D65CsI55zTsk5otzSoJI

Now try reading /dev/urandom with od:
awk '
function rand_string(i) {
    arg=i*4
    cmd="od -A n -t u1 -N " arg " /dev/urandom"  # this is POSIX
    #             ^  ^                unsigned character
    #                   ^  ^          count of i*4 bytes
    s=""
    min=48
    max=123
    while (length(s)<i) {
        while((cmd | getline line)>0) {
            split(line, la)
            for (e in la) {
                if (la[e]<min || la[e]>max) continue
                c=sprintf("%c", la[e])
                if (c~/[[:alnum:]]/) s=s c
            }
        }
        close(cmd)
    }
    return substr(s,1,i)
}
BEGIN {for(i=1;i<=5;i++) print rand_string(20) }'

This works as desired. Prints:
sYY195x6fFQdYMrOn1OS
9mv7KwtgdUu2DgslQByo
LyVvVauEBZU2Ad6kVY9q
WFsJXvw8YWYmySIP87Nz
AMcZY2hKNzBhN1ByX7LW

But now the problem is with the pipe od -A n -t u1 -N " arg " /dev/urandom is is really slow -- unusable except for a trivial number of strings.
Any idea how I can modify one of those awks so that it:

Runs on most platforms (i.e., default POSIX kit);
Can produce reasonably random strings of X length rapidly.

This question has been asked a few times:

How can I replace a string with a random alphanumeric string 48 characters long using awk where the answer is use external tools -- too slow;
Substitute given pattern with a random one with awk but that is a random int and does not use srand;
Execute a command (to generate random strings) inside awk but again uses shell pipe (too slow) and Linux only.


If you need it to be fast, you could use a language like C or C++ or perhaps even java. Generating 1,000,000 random strings of length 20 shouldn't take a second.

Why not pwgen -1 -N <howmany> <howlong> ?? (0.003 sec)

@DavidC.Rankin: Great idea, but not POSIX.

Yes, it's a small C program from that MIT place. It's a bit dated, and could probably be updated with sha256, etc.., but it works incredibly well for what it does. GPLv2 is a plus as well. I hadn't looked at the source before (just checked following your comment). It has had quite a bit of development and rewrite over the years. There is a good history at the end of the man-page.

why are most of your ruby strings 21 characters long if you want 20 characters?

@jhnc:  because my string slice is off by one on that one!

I don't speak ruby but wouldn't just an obiwan make all the strings too long? so something about the select maybe?

I don't know what I'm doing but changing (0..len) to (1..1) seems to fix it

or whatever the idiomatic version of (c=(min + rand(max-min)).chr)[pattern] && rtr+=c is and just return rtr

@jhnc: I have a better Ruby in my answer...

I don't have access to Ruby but on my (apparently slow!) system the awk script from @dawgs answer takes 24 seconds to run while this one takes 5 seconds:
$ cat tst.sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

time awk -v r=$RANDOM '
function rand_string(n,         s,i) {
    for ( i=1; i<=n; i++ ) {
        s = s chars[int(1+rand()*numChars)]
    }
    return s
}
BEGIN{
    srand(r)      # Use srand ONCE only
    for (i=48; i<=122; i++) {
        char = sprintf("%c", i)
        if ( char ~ /[[:alnum:]]/ ) {
            chars[++numChars] = char
        }
    }

    for (i=1; i<=1000000; i++) {print rand_string(20)}
}' | sort | uniq -c | awk '$1>1'


$ ./tst.sh

real    0m5.078s
user    0m4.077s
sys     0m0.045s

so if you want to produce a lot of strings then create an array of the possible letters first and then index the array using rand() instead of calling sprintf() for every letter of every string.
Since making a variable like s iteratively larger is slow in terms of memory [re]allocation, you can make the script about 20% faster still by setting OFS="" then setting $i to each char rather than building up a string:
function rand_string(n,         i) {
    for ( i=1; i<=n; i++ ) {
        $i = chars[int(1+rand()*numChars)]
    }
    return $0
}


$ ./tst2.sh

real    0m3.954s
user    0m3.420s
sys     0m0.015s

as long as you don't need $0 for anything else.

practically, even with the birthday paradox, I think the likelihood of a collision between 62^20 values is infinitesimal (I tried to calculate it, but my arbitrary precision calculator just returned "Very large factorial"...)

@jhnc : then you need to fix your "arbitrary precision calculator", cuz 62^20 only has copies of 2 and 31, which shouldn't be any type of factorial (or its variants). If you're talking about 2^5 = 32 to make it adjacent, that would result in  31s outweighing 32s by a 5:1 ratio

@RAREKpopManifesto I was referring to now-deleted comments re uniq -c. 62 character alphabet by 20 character string = 62^20 possible strings (n). Generate 1000000 strings randomly (k). Probability all strings are different = n! / ( (n-k)! * n^k ).

I don't know a closed form but brute-forcing, it looks to be around 0.99999999999999999999999929020035 so I guess if a collision ever occurred it would demonstrate the random number generator is biased or that there's a bug in the code

@jhnc : ahhh the way I think about making something truly random isn't so much about just using longer and longer keys, but a combination of different sources of randomness, including ones that aren't algorithm based, inventing non-sensible mathematical transformations between them, then also doing some non math-based transformations in between. That way you've minimized chances of single points of failure. This isn't about "security through obscurity", but rather, one simply can't conjure up attacks upon things that have no math basis to it.

@RAREKpopManifesto ?? I'm not trying to make anything random. I am not trying to attack anything. My comment was simply to note that testing for collisions in the generated strings was probably unnecessary. If you generated a million strings every nanosecond from the start of the universe until now (approx 4e26 trials), it looks like you'd only expect to see any collisions at all in around 300 of those trials. That's "practically" "infinitesimal".

$ awk '
    function get20(){
        "tr -dc A-Za-z0-9 </dev/urandom | fold -b20" | getline s
        return s
    }
    BEGIN {
        for (i=1; i<=10; ++i)
            print get20()
    }
'
ds3bnaDUlYhxETdwTUwT
1OgMbkoAfcptTHG8guPd
RJQj2e1MbU1PVsQ0biGo
pAo7NlaOwXUSkgxG8ZAS
fESVcYBK5cBOBQxCDQ3T
ZZqE454jIiUc7oEtwPry
IX4WSw47pvbhoQ8zdXLy
pOM2bZjQVolek35nuCWt
deAa9ddHhGeX8FJGJFCb
NH5FTSWNKcvzYnTkvewM
$


$ time gawk '
    function get20(){
        "tr -dc A-Za-z0-9 </dev/urandom | fold -b20" | getline s
        return s
    }
    BEGIN {
        for (i=1; i<=1000000; ++i)
            len += length(get20())
        print len
    }
'
20000000

real    0m0.522s
user    0m0.782s
sys 0m0.263s
$

$ time mawk '
    function get20(){
        "tr -dc A-Za-z0-9 </dev/urandom | fold -b20" | getline s
        return s
    }
    BEGIN {
        for (i=1; i<=1000000; ++i)
            len += length(get20())
        print len
    }
'
20000000

real    0m0.534s
user    0m0.145s
sys 0m0.013s
$

$ time busybox awk '
    function get20(){
        "tr -dc A-Za-z0-9 </dev/urandom | fold -b20" | getline s
        return s
    }
    BEGIN {
        for (i=1; i<=1000000; ++i)
            len += length(get20())
        print len
    }
'
20000000

real    0m1.344s
user    0m1.703s
sys 0m0.416s
$

Xubuntu 24.04.1 on i5-8350U

I have just found: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/230673/how-to-generate-a-random-string
which has an answer using the same approach. There's a note that setting LC_ALL=C for the tr command may be desirable.

To allow variable length output, selecting a suitably large/small value for the fold parameter and accumulating a small number of getline might be almost as fast. Perhaps twice the typical desired length might be a reasonable choice? So for 20, something like:
awk -v chunksz=40 '
    BEGIN {
        randomchunk = "tr -dc A-Za-z0-9 </dev/urandom | fold -b" chunksz
    }
    function getn_alnum(n,        i,s,r){
        for (i=0; i<n; i+=chunksz) {
            randomchunk | getline s
            r = r s
        }
        return substr(r,1,n)
    }
    # ...
'


I like it. Compare with time pwgen -1 -N 10 20 (0m0.008s, 0m0.003s, 0m0.001s)

@DavidC.Rankin but compare with time pwgen -1 -N 1000000 20 >/dev/null ...

Ooof -- it's still running... (real 0m27.378s) -- point made.

@DavidC.Rankin my machine is slow. take 1m7s here

/dev/urandom is the culprit. It can inject delay when large amounts of data are requested. The man page provides a little detail about its reliance on the kernel entropy pool. I wonder how awk avoids the same issue? Also likely an issue with the fact pwgen hasn't been updated in the past 7 years. Lots of kernel development during that time.

I like it. Interestingly, on OS X, it is very fast when using gawk but the BSD release native to OS X it prints the strings but then hangs. Perhaps waiting for an explicit close for the open pipe?

I don't have access to OS X but on a real BSD system it seems to terminate correctly (awk version 20121220 (FreeBSD)). What if you add an explicit exit?

What if you add an explicit exit? Nope. I tried closing the pipe, explicit exit, adding a while((cmd | getline s)>0) and all hang on OS X. The LC_ALL=C is required on OS X since tr is expecting UTF-8 without that and /dev/urandom is just producing random bytes.

I meant BEGIN{for(i=1; i<=10; ++i) print get20(); exit; } ? Perhaps it is erroneously trying to read stdin. Does just awk 'BEGIN {print "hello"}' also hang? Maybe try giving a /dev/null file argument?

I did fix the awk / gawk thing: It was the code editor I was using as an interactive shell.

Of course running od, or any external process, 1 million times is going to take time. But you don't really need Awk here at all.
base64 -w 20 /dev/urandom | head -n 1000000

If you need a different alphabet than that provided by base64, there are tools like base85 which are however less ubiquitous.
Notably, the base64 alphabet includes / and +. If those are unacceptable, you can add a simple tr postprocessing step:
base64 -w 20 /dev/urandom | head -n 1000000 | tr /+ 0-9A-Za-z

The distribution will then be slightly less random again, but probably not enough to make any real difference.
I don't have Ruby here so I can't directly compare, but the timings for this on my Debian VM are
bash$ time base64 -w 20 /dev/urandom | head -n 1000000 >/dev/null
real    0m0.064s
user    0m0.033s
sys 0m0.034s

For indirect comparison, Ed Morton's first Awk script takes 2 seconds real time here.  Adding the tr pipeline pushes this to 0.081s real time.
Unfortunately, base64 on MacOS doesn't support the -w option at all. If you insist on running it inside Awk, try something like
#!/bin/awk -f

BEGIN {
  cmd = "base64 </dev/urandom | fold -w 20"
  while ((cmd | getline result) > 0) {
      gsub(/[\/+]/, "", result)
      print(result)
      if (++lines >= 1000000) exit;
  }
}

Unfortunately, this is much slower (slightly below 3.5 seconds real time on my system).

plugging base64|tr into my code in place of my tr|fold makes it run about 20% faster. I know base64 encoding can be optimised (and fold probably isn't) and base64 makes more efficient use of /dev/urandom than tr, so seems a win all round

The command is base64 -w 20 -i /dev/urandom | head -n XXX on Mac OS

Hmm, the stock base64 on MacOS does not seem to support the -w option at all. Drats.

base64 </dev/urandom | fold -w 20 | head -n 1000000 works, and takes 0.569s real time on my Mac.

I actually have gotten this to work in gawk only. I 1) Use cmd="base64 -w " arg " -i /dev/urandom | head -n 10000" where arg is the desired width + 20%; 2) read that pipe into gawk and remove the /+ with gsub and then 3) slice the string to the desired length. Very performant. I am frustrated that Mac OS awk seems to hang on sys pipes on a whim, but for gawk -- this is great.

You can reimplement head in Awk trivially, too.

I tried that. The issue seems to be how Mac OS awk tries to terminate reading from the pipe... I was struggling with the same issue with jhnc's answer.

Thanks for the awk demo. Take a look at my answer to see another take on the same. On Mac OS 15.0, base64 DOES have a -w argument.

why not user+sys (to first approximation and ignoring I/O)? is real a useful measure even on a nominally idle system? If I do sleep 100 the  resources actually used are minimal even if real is 100 seconds.

Well I have Sonoma 14.7 here and it doesn't support -w. Nice to hear if they finally updated it in the forthcoming release but for the time being, most of us are probably still on Sonoma (or older still).

@jhnc With really simple code like this, there is obviously no sleep in there. Wall clock time seemed like the most informative measure out of the ones I got for this scenario. For what it's worth, I got approx 1.5 user + 2.5 sys out of the final Awk, for example, but I specifically wanted to avoid getting bogged down in detailed numbers.

base64 doesn't seem to be POSIX as the OP requested, at least I couldn't find it at https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9799919799/.

@EdMorton True; frankly, I missed that requirement.

Take awk 1 and do this:
time awk -v r=$RANDOM '
function rand_string(i) {
    s=""
    min=48
    max=123
    #srand(r) Duh!! WRONG! Only use srand once or it resets to the same sequence
    while (length(s)<i) {
        c=sprintf("%c", int(min+rand()*(max-min+1)))
        if (c~/[[:alnum:]]/) s=s c
    }
    return s
}
BEGIN{ 
    srand(r)      # Use srand ONCE only
    for (i=1; i<=1000000; i++) {print rand_string(20)}
}'  1> /dev/null

real    0m6.690s
user    0m6.677s
sys 0m0.012s

Which I rewrote (looking at Ed Morton's answer) to be:
time awk -v r=$RANDOM '
function fill_buf(low, high,          i, char) {
    # We WANT chars and numChars to be global...
    for(i=low; i<=high; i++) {
        char = sprintf("%c", i)
        if ( char ~ /[[:alnum:]]/ ) {
            chars[++numChars] = char
        }
    }
}
function rand_string(n,         s,i) {
    if (numChars=="") fill_buf(48,123)
    for ( i=1; i<=n; i++ ) {
        s = s chars[int(1+rand()*numChars)]
    }
    return s
}
BEGIN{ 
    srand(r)      # Use srand ONCE only
    for (i=1; i<=1000000; i++) {print rand_string(20)}
}' 1> /dev/null 

real    0m6.765s
user    0m6.747s
sys 0m0.017s

VS the (vastly improved) Ruby:
time ruby -e 'def rand_string(len, min=48, max=123, pat=/[[:alnum:]]/)
    # @tgt ||= means only run the first time this function is called
    @tgt ||= (min..max).map(&:chr).grep(pat)
    (1..len).map{ @tgt.sample }.join
end

1_000_000.times{puts rand_string(20)}' 1> /dev/null


real    0m1.634s
user    0m1.632s
sys 0m0.035s

So the Ruby is a bit faster -- as expected. (But if you use gawk vs awk the gawk completes in 6.2 seconds.)
I am not sure I believe that Ruby timing. When I run it on a server it is more similar to gawk. But I am reporting it. Apple M3 PowerBook with Ruby 3.3.5. Version 3+ has been a vast speedup.)
I also use tripleee's answer to write an awk / gawk version that maintains a buffer of reads to /dev/urandom through base64 translating it to -w  size strings:
time gawk '
function fill_buf(w,         cmd, line, arg) {
    # buf and buf_idx purposely global
    
    split("", buf)   
    buf_idx=1
    arg=int(w+w*0.2)
    cmd="base64 -w " arg " -i /dev/urandom | head -n 10000"
    while((cmd | getline line)>0) {
        gsub(/[^[:alnum:]]|[[:space:]]/, "", line)
        if (length(line)<w) continue
        buf[buf_idx++]=substr(line, 1, w)
    }
    close(cmd)
    buf_idx=1
}

function rand_string(w) {
    # Note: if you use length(buf) PRIOR to it being used as an array -- 
    # it is marked forever as a scalar
    if (buf_idx==0 || length(buf)-buf_idx==-1) fill_buf(w)
    return buf[buf_idx++]
}

BEGIN {
for(i=1;i<=1000000;i++) print rand_string(20) 
}' 1> /dev/null 

Which is VERY performant:
real    0m1.042s
user    0m0.995s
sys 0m0.293s


I created a Bash / Perl benchmark for these routines HERE
tl; dr

Perl fastest;
g?awk with base64 reads in batches almost as fast as Perl;
Ed Morton's awk / gawk fast and will run anywhere;
Ruby is fast and fastest to write -- if you know Ruby.

Bash performance comparisons:
$ perl tst.pl
                  Rate awk abd 1 awk abd 2 awk EdM ruby abd gawk EdM gawk abd 2 awk abd base64 gawk abd base64 perl abd
awk abd 1       9.78/s        --      -32%    -32%     -54%     -72%       -73%           -73%            -73%     -74%
awk abd 2       14.3/s       46%        --     -1%     -33%     -59%       -60%           -60%            -61%     -63%
awk EdM         14.5/s       48%        1%      --     -32%     -59%       -59%           -60%            -60%     -62%
ruby abd        21.5/s      119%       50%     48%       --     -39%       -40%           -40%            -41%     -44%
gawk EdM        35.2/s      260%      146%    143%      64%       --        -1%            -2%             -3%      -8%
gawk abd 2      35.7/s      265%      150%    146%      66%       1%         --            -1%             -1%      -6%
awk abd base64  36.0/s      268%      152%    148%      68%       2%         1%             --             -1%      -6%
gawk abd base64 36.2/s      270%      154%    150%      69%       3%         1%             1%              --      -5%
perl abd        38.2/s      290%      167%    163%      78%       8%         7%             6%              5%       --

zsh performance comparisons:
% perl tst.pl
                  Rate awk abd 1 awk abd 2 awk EdM ruby abd gawk abd base64 awk abd base64 gawk abd 2 gawk EdM perl abd
awk abd 1       9.69/s        --      -32%    -33%     -55%            -73%           -73%       -73%     -73%     -74%
awk abd 2       14.2/s       47%        --     -1%     -34%            -61%           -61%       -61%     -61%     -62%
awk EdM         14.4/s       49%        1%      --     -33%            -60%           -60%       -60%     -61%     -62%
ruby abd        21.6/s      122%       51%     50%       --            -41%           -41%       -41%     -41%     -43%
gawk abd base64 36.2/s      274%      154%    151%      68%              --             0%         0%      -1%      -4%
awk abd base64  36.2/s      274%      154%    151%      68%              0%             --         0%      -1%      -4%
gawk abd 2      36.2/s      274%      154%    151%      68%              0%             0%         --      -1%      -4%
gawk EdM        36.5/s      277%      156%    153%      69%              1%             1%         1%       --      -3%
perl abd        37.6/s      288%      164%    161%      74%              4%             4%         4%       3%       --

Running that on a MacBook Pro M3 with:
gawk 5.3
Ruby 3.3
Bash 5.2
zsh 5.9
MacOS 15.0


I don't use ruby so maybe a stupid question ... how does (0..1_000_000) work? is it processed like a for (i=1; i<=1000000; i++)? or is it processed like a bash / {0..1000000} where there's an extra cpu/memory/time overhead to first generate the 1,000,001 values and then step through them in a loop? if the latter then that could be a large part of the increased timing; does ruby have something like for (i=1; i<=1000000; i++) that might reduce overall timing?

Both kinda sorta. There is no C style loop in Ruby. The object (0..1000000) is a range. It is not expanded into a million (+1) numbers like Bash. It creates an iterator that you can then loop over with .each{|n| loop}. Alternative constructs would be 0.upto(1000000) { |n| loop } and 1000001.times { |n| loop } (As I write this, I realize there is one additional loop in the Ruby vs the awk...) There are definitely ways to slightly speed up the Ruby. My main focus was the function. Took me maybe 3 minutes in Ruby and more than an hour in awk.  I think you would like Ruby...

thanks for the explanation re: (0..1_000_000); as for awk vs ruby ... I'd say it depends on what we know at the moment ... OP's repeated calls to srand(r), in conjunction with the duplicate outputs, stands out like a flashing neon sign so I'd say it took me ~15 secs to ascertain the same fix for the awk code (though it would take a few more mins to write up) ... but knowing no ruby it would take me at least an hour (+ a couple days) :-)

It's not clear to me what the benchmark shows. Do you want to generate a fixed (per run) number of strings of fixed (per run) length? In which case triplee's comment re why wrap his generator inside awk at all? If either length is intended to be variable, then the benchmark seems not so useful since implementations will need to change significantly

My original project started out a simple txt database that would label the D part of certain fields with either a full numeric OR a random string based on some other parameters. Essentially some fields would be selected and others allowed randomly to bubble to the top of the pile in a DSU sort. Millions of records and dozens of files. I started in awk. But the lack of this easy random string utility made me go to Ruby. It just seemed like basic functionality to have a true random string function inside awk. Then it just became interesting. That is the 'why'. The Perl and Ruby are just alts.

So basically the benchmark is an indicator if you wanted a fairly generic fastish random string generator in awk -- here are several good starting places. Simple to little more complicated. I guess you could just generate a huge file of random strings, but you would have to test if you reach the end and regenerate entirely if you want a different size or character set of string.

And it is interesting that Ed Morton's very simple and absolutely POSIX compliant is among the fastest on gawk. That is the most solid one I think.


That does not work -- same seed, same string result.

This is compliant with what The GNU Awk User's manual says about srand

rand([x])
Set the starting point, or seed, for generating random numbers to the value x.
Each seed value leads to a particular sequence of random numbers.49 Thus, if the seed is set to the same value a second time,
the same sequence of random numbers is produced again.
CAUTION: Different awk implementations use different random-number generators internally. Don’t expect the same awk program
to produce the same series of random numbers when executed by
different versions of awk.
If the argument x is omitted, as in srand(), then the current date and time of day are used for a seed. This is the way to get random numbers that are truly unpredictable.
The return value of srand() is the previous seed. This makes it easy to keep track of the seeds in case you need to consistently
reproduce sequences of random numbers.
POSIX does not specify the initial seed; it differs among awk implementations.

Last 4 words are especially important considering you are stipulating

Runs on most platforms (i.e., default POSIX kit)

